# How can I make this C# code more efficient?

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code as follows: it retrieves a Json string, parses it, and if required sets the value in the specific node:

```
 JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(JsonString);
 dynamic dModel = jObject;                                
 var url = dModel.Value<string>("Urllink");
```

How can I change this to something like below by using the `?` expression?

```
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
     url = url;
 else
     url = "#_urlString";
```

How can I make lines 1 - 5 more efficient?

Comment: Have you looked at all at [the documentation for the C# ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)? (that's what it's called)  And how do you mean "more efficient"? By what metric? And in what use case does it matter? Your code consists of a bunch of assignments and a single flow control statement - how exactly do you expect a speedup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
url=string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url) ? url : "#_urlString";
```

Comment: one question , if i do it using your suggestion , url=string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url) ? url : "#_urlString";  Unnecessary assignment of value to url ?

Comment: so really i could do   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))     url = "#_urlString";